# How to make Bukkit not save chunks automatically at any time

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Bukkit saves automatically every few minutes, and also saves when it shuts down.

I need a way to not save the chunks, because I'm in need of a system to make my minigame map to be completely fresh when the server restarts, for another round of the minimap.

What I tried to do:

- Setting the save-automatically off in the server.properties;
- Running the following to try to shutdown without saving:

```
Bukkit.getServer().unloadWorld(getServer().getWorlds().get(0), false);
Bukkit.shutdown();
```

Comment: I won't put this as an answer because it ignores the title question,  but how about instead of altering the game so it doesn't save, you just create a backup of the map as you want it to be at the start of the game, then write a simple batch/shell script which deletes the map, copies the backup map into its place, and then starts the server?

Comment: If it's easier to just make Bukkit not to save, and reload the map instead, would make it a lot easier to me, but if it's the only possibility, then that's what I'm probrably gonna do...

Comment: There's a method (if I remember correctly) for `World` that sets a preference for saving chunks. It's been a while since I've messed with Bukkit, though.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove The method is Bukkit.getServer().getWorlds().get(0).setAutoSave(false);

But it doesn't work aswell.

Comment: It does not work because the world is saved on shutdown.

Comment: @Joiner
Yes, and how to make it not save?

Comment: I have already answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27295390/3453226).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried is the correct way to do this.
The problem is that you cannot unload default worlds (which are the Overworld, the Nether and the End).
You have to create a new one.

You need a `WorldCreator` object.

```
WorldCreator seed = new WorldCreator("arena");
World arena = seed.createWorld();
```

This is a custom world: regions are saved (if not set otherwise) but Bukkit will not know about it after the server restarts.
So you must run the code above the first time to generate the files, then to load them from disk if found.

Comment: Yes, but My World is a custom one, and not a seed-based one, I don't know if I understanted you though.

Comment: @Kerooker It is impossible because `Server.getWorlds().get(0)` always returns the Overworld.

Comment: Yes, I got 0 to try to make Overworld not save, but it still does.

Comment: @Kerooker In fact! Have you read my answer? **You cannot unload default worlds.**

Comment: But wouldn't using the seed generate a world different from the one I have on my file?

Comment: @Kerooker I named it `seed` but it does not represent a seed number. See the edit.